# Apple secure enclave with RFC6979

Tags: ios, cryptography, enclave

Does Apple secure enclave support rfc6979 with P256 curve? This RFC defines a deterministic ecdsa with a deterministic k value.

THATS LINK OF THE RFC https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6979

I looked everywhere in their documentation but couldn't find a mention of such usage

Answer (score 0):

We could guess what the underlying implementation could be by looking at the [Swift Crypto GitHub page](https://github.com/apple/swift-crypto) and see how they implemented the non Apple platform. Of course, this does not guarantee that the Apple platform uses the same implementation internally.

Looking at the [implementation of the NIST curves](https://github.com/apple/swift-crypto/blob/main/Sources/Crypto/Keys/EC/BoringSSL/NISTCurvesKeys_boring.swift#L304), we can see that a call to `ECDSA_do_sign` is made. We can look for [this symbol](https://github.com/google/boringssl/blob/50e30518df5022a86309d20d8c7471ed4c2f5a7e/crypto/fipsmodule/ecdsa/ecdsa.c#L307) in the BoringSSL repository, where we can [clearly see](https://github.com/google/boringssl/blob/50e30518df5022a86309d20d8c7471ed4c2f5a7e/crypto/fipsmodule/ecdsa/ecdsa.c#L346) that it still uses the `k` value.

So it appears that the NIST curves still are not using the RFC 6979 standard. If you want to be sure, you can also try to insert an issue ticket in the GitHub repository of Swift Crypto.